# Is there a way to generate angular component by selector in service?

Tags: angular

I have a box where I want to generate some html code, the box is genereted programiticaly in service which is injected in root, components are lazy loaded, but I only want to use that service and generate window if everything is loaded.

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class GenerationService {

    public generateWindow(someAdditionalContent) {
      return '<window-selector class="window-container">' +
              someAdditionalContent +
              '</window-selector>'
    } 
}
```

Is there a posibility to use compoenent in that way?